# Postgresql column containg regular expressions to match against

Tags: regex, postgresql

I was just wondering if there is a specific postgres column type for regular expression patterns. That is, I want to store patterns in a column and then query for the ones that match an input string literal. Is there a better way than just making a TEXT column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no specific column type for storing regular expressions.

Unfortunately, you will have to actually run each regular expression on your string literal in order to find out if it's a match.

**Edit**
I thought that a varchar column would save space but after reading @muistooshort's comment and doing some research it seems that varchar columns don't hold much benefit over text columns in postgresql. I find this amusing and a bit odd.

Comment: `varchar` is actually an anachronism in PostgreSQL; `varchar`, `char`, and `text` are pretty much the same thing inside PostgreSQL so you should always use `text` unless you have a specific reason to limit the column size.

Comment: @muistooshort really?
There is no difference in terms of space allocated?

Comment: @Strae - as the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html) say: _The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case of character. Longer strings have 4 bytes of overhead instead of 1. Long strings are compressed by the system automatically, so the physical requirement on disk might be less. Very long values are also stored in background tables so that they do not interfere with rapid access to shorter column values._

Comment: @Strae - and about performance: _There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text or character varying should be used instead._

Comment: @dezso: Thanks for stepping in while I was off being lazy and sleeping :)